# UnicodeEncodeError with installing uPyCraft

Tags: python, iot, nodemcu

I really need help.
I want to program my nodeMCU with python using uPyCraft. When I install it and wanted to run the app it give me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uPyCraft.py", line 2965, in <module>
  File "uPyCraft.py", line 140, in __init__
  File "uPyCraft.py", line 902, in createBasicConfig
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 286-290: character maps to <undefined>
```

can someone help me, please!

Comment: Can you please tell the python version and OS type?

Comment: I am using python 3.9 and windows 10.

Comment: As gitrepo mentioned 3.4 is supported python version refer this link https://github.com/DFRobot/uPyCraft_src

Comment: so I have to install python 3.4?

Comment: Yes try that and let me know

Comment: Think carefully about starting off with uPyCraft. It has last seen updates on Sep 7, 2018.

Comment: its not working